# How to Use TestStreams with a MultiOutput Class in Apache Beam Java

Tags: java, testing, apache-beam

I am trying to trying to write a Beam Streaming pipeline, that simply reads from a PubSub Queue, parses the data and writes to either one of two BigQuery Tables. So code takes advantage of side outputs to write to one of two tables from within the DoFn. I am running into the following error message: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: unable to serialize DoFnAndMainOutput{doFn=com.pipeline.PubSubToBigQuery$ParsePubSubMessage@50eca7c6, mainOutputTag=Tag}. I will attach the full error message, DoFn and Test class below:

DoFn:

```
public static class PubsubMessageToTableRow
            extends PTransform<PCollection<PubsubMessage>, PCollectionTuple> {

        private TupleTag<TableRow> soundEventReadings;
        private TupleTag<TableRow> doorEventReadings;

        public PubsubMessageToTableRow(TupleTag<TableRow> soundEventReadings, TupleTag<TableRow> doorEventReadings){
            this.soundEventReadings = soundEventReadings;
            this.doorEventReadings = doorEventReadings;
        }

        @Override
        public PCollectionTuple expand(PCollection<PubsubMessage> input) {

            return input.apply("Parse PubSub Message",
                    ParDo.of(new ParsePubSubMessage(soundEventReadings, doorEventReadings))
                    .withOutputTags(soundEventReadings, TupleTagList.of(doorEventReadings)));

        }
    }

    /**
     * Parse the PubSub Json message and create either a Door or Sound Event. Then create a TableRow object from the
     * event objects.
     */
    public static class ParsePubSubMessage extends DoFn<PubsubMessage, TableRow> {

        private final TupleTag<TableRow> soundEventReadings;
        private final TupleTag<TableRow> doorEventReadings;

        public ParsePubSubMessage(TupleTag<TableRow> soundEventReadings,
                                  TupleTag<TableRow> doorEventReadings) {
            this.soundEventReadings = soundEventReadings;
            this.doorEventReadings = doorEventReadings;
        }


        @ProcessElement
        public void processElement(ProcessContext c, MultiOutputReceiver out) throws IOException{
            PubsubMessage message = c.element();
            String jsonString = new String(message.getPayload(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

            // A DoorEvent can either be a door open/close event signified with #door# in the SensorName or can
            // be a motion event from the motion sensor next to the door signified with #motion# in the SensorName
            if (jsonString.contains("#door#") || jsonString.contains("#motion#")){
                DoorEvent doorEvent = mapper.readValue(jsonString, DoorEvent.class);
                out.get(doorEventReadings).output(doorEvent.toTableRow());
            } else if (jsonString.contains("noiseFloor")){
                SoundEvent soundEvent = mapper.readValue(jsonString, SoundEvent.class);
                out.get(soundEventReadings).output(soundEvent.toTableRow());
            }
        }
    }
```

Test

```
 @Rule
    public final transient TestPipeline testPipeline = TestPipeline.create();

    @Test
    public void testPubsubMessageToTableRow() throws IOException{
        String jsonDoorEvent = "{\"EventID\":\"12\",\"HomeID\":" +
                "\"22222\",\"SmartThingsSensorName\":" +
                "\"sa#door#1#front_door\",\"State\":\"closed\",\"Label\":false," +
                "\"HasBeenLabelled\":false,\"EventTime\":\"2019-01-09T12:22:22Z\",\"CreateDate\":" +
                "\"2019-01-09T15:17:00Z\",\"ModifyDate\":\"2019-01-09T15:17:00Z\"}";

        TableRow door = doorEvent.toTableRow();

        TableRow outputDoorRow = new TableRow().set("EventID", "12")
                .set("HomeID", "22222")
                .set("SmartThingsSensorName", "sa#door#1#front_door")
                .set("State", "closed")
                .set("Label", false)
                .set("HasBeenLabelled", false)
                .set("EventTime", "2019-01-09T12:22:22Z")
                .set("CreateDate", "2019-01-09T15:17:00Z")
                .set("ModifyDate", "2019-01-09T15:17:00Z");

        Map<String, String> attributes = new HashMap<>();
        attributes.put("eventTime", "2019-01-09T12:22:22Z");
        PubsubMessage messageDoor = new PubsubMessage(jsonDoorEvent.getBytes(), attributes);

        final TupleTag<TableRow> doorEventReadings = new TupleTag<TableRow>(){};

        TestStream<PubsubMessage> createEvent =
                TestStream.create(PubsubMessageWithAttributesCoder.of())
                .addElements(messageDoor).advanceWatermarkToInfinity();

        PCollectionTuple tuple = testPipeline
                .apply("Create Stream", createEvent)
                .apply("Parse pipeline",
                        new PubSubToBigQuery.PubsubMessageToTableRow(soundEventReadings, doorEventReadings));

        PCollection<TableRow> doorEventOutput = tuple.get(doorEventReadings);
        PAssert.that(doorEventOutput).containsInAnyOrder(outputDoorRow);

        testPipeline.run().waitUntilFinish();
     }
```

StackTrace:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: unable to serialize DoFnAndMainOutput{doFn=com.pipeline.PubSubToBigQuery$ParsePubSubMessage@50eca7c6, mainOutputTag=Tag<output>}

    at org.apache.beam.sdk.util.SerializableUtils.serializeToByteArray(SerializableUtils.java:57)
    at org.apache.beam.repackaged.beam_runners_direct_java.runners.core.construction.ParDoTranslation.translateDoFn(ParDoTranslation.java:462)
    at org.apache.beam.repackaged.beam_runners_direct_java.runners.core.construction.ParDoTranslation$1.translateDoFn(ParDoTranslation.java:160)
    at org.apache.beam.repackaged.beam_runners_direct_java.runners.core.construction.ParDoTranslation.payloadForParDoLike(ParDoTranslation.java:695)
    at org.apache.beam.repackaged.beam_runners_direct_java.runners.core.construction.ParDoTranslation.translateParDo(ParDoTranslation.java:156)
    at org.apache.beam.repackaged.beam_runners_direct_java.runners.core.construction.ParDoTranslation$ParDoPayloadTranslator.translate(ParDoTranslation.java:111)
    at org.apache.beam.repackaged.beam_runners_direct_java.runners.core.construction.PTransformTranslation.toProto(PTransformTranslation.java:206)
    at org.apache.beam.repackaged.beam_runners_direct_java.runners.core.construction.ParDoTranslation.getParDoPayload(ParDoTranslation.java:547)
    at org.apache.beam.repackaged.beam_runners_direct_java.runners.core.construction.ParDoTranslation.isSplittable(ParDoTranslation.java:557)
    at org.apache.beam.repackaged.beam_runners_direct_java.runners.core.construction.PTransformMatchers$4.matches(PTransformMatchers.java:194)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline$2.visitPrimitiveTransform(Pipeline.java:278)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.runners.TransformHierarchy$Node.visit(TransformHierarchy.java:668)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.runners.TransformHierarchy$Node.visit(TransformHierarchy.java:660)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.runners.TransformHierarchy$Node.visit(TransformHierarchy.java:660)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.runners.TransformHierarchy$Node.access$600(TransformHierarchy.java:311)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.runners.TransformHierarchy.visit(TransformHierarchy.java:245)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.traverseTopologically(Pipeline.java:458)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.replace(Pipeline.java:256)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.replaceAll(Pipeline.java:209)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.direct.DirectRunner.run(DirectRunner.java:170)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.direct.DirectRunner.run(DirectRunner.java:66)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.run(Pipeline.java:311)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.testing.TestPipeline.run(TestPipeline.java:348)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.testing.TestPipeline.run(TestPipeline.java:329)
    at com.ecobee.hm_occupancy_data_pipeline.PubSubToBigQueryTest.testPubsubMessageToTableRow(PubSubToBigQueryTest.java:118)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.testing.TestPipeline$1.evaluate(TestPipeline.java:317)
    at org.junit.rules.RunRules.evaluate(RunRules.java:20)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: com.pipeline.PubSubToBigQueryTest
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1184)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1509)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1509)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1509)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:348)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.util.SerializableUtils.serializeToByteArray(SerializableUtils.java:53)
    ... 48 more
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in the log: `java.io.NotSerializableException: com.pipeline.PubSubToBigQueryTest`. Make your test implement `Serializable`, this should solve it. Or try moving all the `DoFns` and other in-line functionality into separate serializable classes.

Comment: Thank you! The solution was to make my Test class implement serializable.